# My first ever CSS grid area code seems to not work ,it cherry picks where it wants to work?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

so i have a grid area called header ,sidebar,content and side bar and content are next to each other and is defined below, sidebar works but content doesnt.how can i make content look like sidebar. image link below so that my question is more clear

```css
.gridcont {
  display: grid;
  background-color: rgb(172, 115, 68);
  border: 20px white;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 250px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "sidebar content" "sidebar content"
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: header;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.item3 {}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gridcont">
    <div class=" item1 item"> grid Item 1 </div>
    <div class=" item2 item">grid Item 2 </div>
    <div class=" item3 item">grid Item 3</div>
    <div class=" item4 item">grid Item 4</div>
    <div class=" item5 item">grid Item 5</div>

  </div>
</body>
```

note that i left item 3 blank cause if i assign content to it it ruins the whole thing. this is what i looks like when it runs  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW93D.png
what i want my result to look like:-
[image: wanted result]

Comment: why you've tagged `laravel`?

Comment: Do you want it to look like the picture?

Comment: Perhaps you could do a sketch of what you want the layout to look like as I’m not at all clear what you want done with item4 and item5.

Comment: The picture showing what you want it to look like has three items in it, but your code has five. Where do you expect the other two items to be displayed?

Comment: @AHaworth i have added a link in the question that shows what i want it to look like

Comment: What about where you want items 4 and 5 to be placed?

Comment: @AHaworth 4 is a segment below 2 and 3 that has full width and 5 is the footer

Comment: If you include them in your grid-template-areas layout you'll have control of where they go.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You were almost there. I added a `width: 479px` `margin: 15px auto` to center it and deleted column-gap just leaving `grid-gap: 30px;` since the row and column-gap are very similar on the image provided. Updated `grid-template-area: "header header" "sidebar content1" "content2 content2" "footer footer"`

As far as the items... .item3 and .item4 just need their own names since they are two different items in the grid .item5 I named footer. I also added the yellow color to them to match the image. I also added some height to each grid item.

```css
.gridcont {
  display: grid;
  width: 479px;
  background-color: rgb(172, 115, 68);
  border: 20px white;
  margin: 15px auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 250px;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header header" 
  "sidebar content1" 
  "content2 content2"
  "footer footer";
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: content1;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: content2;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}

.item1, .item5 {
  height: 50px;
}

.item2, .item3, .item4 {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gridcont">
    <div class=" item1 item"> grid Item 1 </div>
    <div class=" item2 item">grid Item 2 </div>
    <div class=" item3 item">grid Item 3</div>
    <div class=" item4 item">grid Item 4</div>
    <div class=" item5 item">grid Item 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That still looks much more like the "what I have" picture than the "what I want" picture.

Comment: I cannot see the full image but I think I know what you are going for now. One moment.

Comment: Really? I have no idea what the OP wants. The question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @quentin item1 is full width item2 and 3 are side by side I would imagine 4 and 4 are full length

Comment: The OP needs to clarify. Answers shouldn't depend on that level of imagination.

Comment: @Quentin I don't feel the need to be so critical of a first time poster so if they don't update the "what I want" image again then I have done all I can for now. Feel free to wait on them to update it.

Comment: I don't think "waiting until the question is clear before posting an answer instead of guessing at what the OP wants" is being particularly critical of them.

Comment: @Quentin grid item 4 is a footer i know how to do it and grid item 5 is discarded , what i want is for my grid item 2 and 3 be side to side and look like the blue themed version but if you run my code here 2 works and fills the bottom but grid item 3 stays the same even if i set the grid area to content.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck, keep coding!